# Dialog built from divs and css doesn't layout correctly

Tags: html, css

I've got a dialog box that isn't displaying correctly, but I can't figure out why. The dialog is made up of a few divs.

The dialog is made up of a parent div that contains three sub divs for the title, body and footer. Each of the sub divs is further divided into 3 sub sub divs for left, center and right. What I can't figure out is why my left footer sub sub div appears to the right of the right side body sub sub div.

I've simplified the html below so the structure is clear.

```
<div class="dialog">
  <div class="titlebar">
    <div class="titlebarleft">
    </div>
    <div class="titlebarcenter">
    </div>
    <div class="titlebarright">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="con">
    <div class="conleft">
    </div>
    <div class="concenter">
    </div>
    <div class="conright">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footerleft">
    </div>
    <div class="footercenter">
    </div>
    <div class="footerright">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Most of the CSS is the same with each of the 3 main sections (titlebar, body, footer)

Title:

```
.titlebar {
    height: 38px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Content:

```
.con {
    background: url("../images/dialog/vertical.png") repeat-y scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Tahoma,"Lucida Grande",Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Footer:

```
.footer {
    font-family: Tahoma,"Lucida Grande",Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 37px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here's the left footer CSS:

```
.footerleft {
    background: url("../images/dialog/static.png") no-repeat scroll 0 -83px transparent;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 9px;
}
```

Here's a picture of the problem: http://s9.postimage.org/ebj6w7ynj/Dialog_Corner.jpg

Comment: add clear:both to your .footer style . it was better if you give us jsfiddle  demo .

Comment: That worked.  Make it an answer and I'll mark it solved.

Comment: +1 for the jfiddle, also, I'm not sure I fully understand your question. When I test out the code the footerleft is actually placed on the left of the footer? check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/GGM8u/

Comment: I'm not familiar with jfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all div elements is display:inline . so if you write a div after a div element , the width of parent element will break div to new line (just if two div width was more than parent width).
now you can set clear:both (floats)  to .footer class to break line before this element .

```
.footer {
    font-family: Tahoma,"Lucida Grande",Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 37px;
    width: 100%;
    clear:both;
}
```

but i am not sure that works in all browsers .